# .aspx page does not render correctly

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Problem:

.aspx pages will not render the css associated with on the masterpage

to see image hold down ctrl and use your mouse wheel to zoom in

[image]

Setup:

1. IIS 7 windows 2008 r2 server
2. .Net framework 4.0
3. I have used the aspnet_regiis.exe -i
4. Static content is enabled
5. Already had a site running, created a virtual directory within its hierarchy and placed  the files within

Page Directive of screenshot page:

```
<%@Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Solomon Conversion.aspx.cs" Inherits="AcuFinal.Solomon_Conversion" %>
```

Asp.Net Code of Master Page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    AcuConvert
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Conversion Data Validation.aspx" 
                            Text="Conversion Data Validation" Value="Conversion Data Validation"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Solomon Conversion" Value="Solomon Conversion" 
                            NavigateUrl="~/Solomon Conversion.aspx">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to look at the iis logs or use fiddler to find out what URLs are being requested for the css and other supporting files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

should be

```
 <link href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Styles/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

as should the rest of urls containing virtual path when they are not properties of server controls.

Comment: I made the changes specified (i.e. MasterPageFile="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Site.Master") %>") but it still renders exactly the same

Comment: You mean the in the page directive? I'd be suprised if that would compile.  You need to use the ~ notation to resolve teh style sheets, not the masterpage.

Comment: @MatthewMartin - of course not, in plain html, which is expected to be rendered as is.

Comment: My thought was that it was not pulling the masterpage correctly do to the visible page directive at the top, the masterpage referencing the css and all, seemed to be a pathing issue all around

Comment: @jvanh1 - you did not show the Page directive at the top of aspx file, so there is nothing I can say about it.

Comment: @Igor - I just added it, it can also be seen on the screen shot I took

Comment: @jvanh1 - as your Page directive seems to render as part of html in the image you showed, I say there is something wrong with it, so it is not recognized as a Page directive. From what you added, the most obvious thing is missing space between @ and the word Page.

Comment: Sorry my comment was aimed at @jvanh1 who wrote the mysterious MasterPageFile="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Site.Master") %>"

Comment: @MatthewMartin the MasterPageFile="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Site.Master") %>" was a take on an answer someone else gave me

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
<link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Styles/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```